# VSCODE always uses Edge to open ctrl_click links (as in launch.json comment) and I want to use Chrome

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running vscode on windows 10 doing primarily Python coding.

When I was modifying my launch.json file, I noticed the comment has a hot link to more info.

However, Ctrl-click on that link always opens the Edge browser, despite the fact my system settings has chrome as the default.

I have searched all (to my knowledge) of the settings in vscode and cannot fix this behavior.  Google and stack overflow searches have turned up nothing in any of the ways I have phrased the search.   I did find one answer that said: go to file-settings-default browser (or something along those lines) and I had no such setting.

At this point I could even live with a definitive "It's not possible."  Anybody else have this issue?

Comment: Usually i noticed that vscode opens it in default browser. wanna try with a open in browser plugin ?

Comment: I was hoping it didn't actually need a plugin/extension for that behavior, but maybe it does...

Comment: VSCode use to open its own kind of browser, but now it opens my default browser. I am using Linux though, so might be different.

Comment: *file-settings* should be *Start->Settings->Apps->Default programs* instead. You'll find *Web Browser* at the end of the list of apps. It may not help, though; it seems MS is hard-coding Edge into most of their products now. Shades of the 90s all over again?

Comment: @KenWhite I already did change my default apps for windows, but vscode is not honoring that.  I wonder what happens when I uninstall edge?  Will it say "sorry, I can't let you do that."?

Comment: I don't know if you can uninstall Edge. MS is acting like it's part of the OS - you don't get to choose whether to update it or not when a new version is released, a new install of Windows sets Edge as the default app for lots of things (including HTML and PDF files), etc..  I removed it from the Taskbar and put IE there instead, and the last update of Edge added itself back to the Taskbar again.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - VSCode does use your "default browser."

Longer answer - I ran into this right after switching to win11, but I assume it's similar in win10.

STEPS
in the operating system, go into:

settings | apps | default apps

and then click on google chrome to change web related settings.

At the top of the screen, I was able to click,
"Make Google Chrome your default browser"
from there,
scroll down to change the setting you want changed by clicking the little "up and to the right arrow in a tiny box" icon.

(Side note: I was finally able to change the setting where pdfs were opening in Edge instead of Acrobat - Happy dance.)